# Negative Modulo confusion

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$$ x \equiv -74 \ mod \ 31 $$

According to [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=-74+mod+31) & [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-74+mod+31) the answer is **19**

Following the method in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/519856/189608) and using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8456653/1964398) I get **12**. Using my calculator with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858633/1964398) yeilds **12** also.

What answer is right? If the web is correct, how do they come about that answer?

Comment: Note that $-74 = -3(31) + 19$. So, $19$ looks like the correct answer here.  Could you show your work for "following the method" in those answers?

Comment: *19* is certainly not "the (correct) answer". At best it is *a* correct answer, and at worst not correct. But that depends on what the question is, which you have not stated.

Comment: @fkraiem of the answers provided, $19$ is the correct one

Answer (score 2):

$x\equiv -74 \equiv -74+31 \equiv -43\equiv -43+31 \equiv -12 \equiv -12+31 \equiv 19 $

Comment: Am getting confused between the 12 and the 19 aren't I? ...

Comment: When I started to learn modulo and I get a negative value I just kept adding the modulo until I get a positive number. So you get -12 not 12. I dont know how you got 12 with your calculator...