# Modulus with negative remainder

Tags: modular-arithmetic

It has [previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519845/modulo-of-a-negative-number) been asked about -a mod b, and, summarizing my gain:

> **-1000 % 9**
>   -1000/9 = -111.111....
>   9*112-1000 = **8**

This is the method I've found to be effective.
1. What is the easiest way to solve this without calculator?
2. Is there a better way to reach this answers with calculator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of tricks. For example,
$$
-1000\equiv-\left(10\right)^{3}\equiv-\left(1\right)^{3}\equiv-1\equiv8\mod{9}
$$
Since
$$
10\equiv1\mod{9}.
$$
I think you should start by reading the [Wikipedia page on modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) in detail.